# Generic and dynamically associated type

Tags: java, generics

Probably, what I will ask is a terrible question, as the JAVA is strong-type language, but I will ask it, to be sure.

I wanted to implement few models, to which jackson will map to.
Let's say that we have a:
SomeObject which have a property value. SomeObject is an interface:

```
interface SomeObject <T> {
    T getValue();
}
```

Value can be a Boolean, can be a List, or can be a simple string. ObjectOne and ObjectTwo implements SomeObject 
I'm wondering, if we will have such object:

```
List<SomeObject> someObject = new ArrayList<>();
```

And we will have in that list: ObjectOne, ObjectTwo if there is a possibility to call getValue on each of those object, and without casting it to given class, get the proper value?
I know I can do something like that:

```
(String) list.get(0).getValue();
```

but is there a way to get such results:

```
String firstItemIsAString = list.get(0).getValue();
ArrayList secondItemIsAnArrayList = list.get(1).getValue();
```

I know that this is not a javascript, but maybe with some help of Generics this may be achivable? 
I will add that item in the list of SomeObjects will be added in such way:

```
List<SomeObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new ObjectOne<String>());
list.add(new ObjectTwo<ArrayList>());
```

Comment: No, generics are a compile time construct. The types must be known at compile time.

Comment: So it's just like I thought. Thank you @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: Perhaps if we knew why you wanted to do this we could suggest a viable alternative.

Comment: Do you know what the actual types will be of each particular element of the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you put a Boolean and an ArrayList together into some Collection, the generic type of the Collection will have to be some common type of both, which just leaves Object - thus you have no information about the types in the collection at all.

To answer your question directly: no, there is no way of saving the type of something within generics as those are gone during runtime.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a helper method would help you pretend Java was less type safe:

```
public interface SomeObject <T> {
    T getValue();
}
public static void main(String...args){
    List<SomeObject<?>> objectList=new ArrayList<SomeObject<?>>();
    String firstItemIsAString = converter(objectList.get(0).getValue());
}
public static <t> t converter(Object input){
    return (t) input;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what this actually does, what its limitations are and why it may or may not be useful.